# Flicker while changing spine animation cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x-2.x

I am having an issue while using spine animation in cocos2dx. Here is the code

```
 skeletonNode = new CCSkeletonAnimation("Snake.json", "Snake.atlas");
   skeletonNode->setAnimation("Walk", true);
   skeletonNode->setScale(1.0);
   skeletonNode->setSlotsToSetupPose();
    CCSize windowSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    skeletonNode->setPosition(ccp(windowSize.width / 2, windowSize.height/2));
    addChild(skeletonNode);
    skeletonNode->release();
```

now when i change using add animation method, then for a second,it flickers while changing animation. I also tried clear animation before adding new animation but same problem.

this is how i change animation

```
skeletonNode->setSlotsToSetupPose();
skeletonNode->addAnimation("Sleep", true);
```

i can not understand why it flickers. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

When you add new animation to current frame it can't sync. with last frame.
so you should mix animation instead of add a new animation i.e.

```
skeletonAnimation->setMix("animation_1", "animation_2", duration);
```